# Peer review edits use of "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." - accuracy?

Tags: discussion

[I've found an interesting question but to me it was unclear,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594556/visual-studio-2013-application-has-stopped-working) so I left a comment asking for information:

> "*I resetted the settings and blablabla but nothing helped.*" More information possibly? Currently your issue is unclear.

And waited for clarification. After OP replies I add my own comment as following:

> I Resetted the settings Cleared the Solution And did all what google said to fix it but no success i don´t know what i could add for Informations lol.. This is all i did.. –  user3720345 *X mins ago*
>
> Please give more information, such as the scope and fields of your settings. –  Unihedron *X-1 mins ago*

I then was bored of waiting for another reply from OP, so I started cleaning up his question for grammar and spelling. I made sure to make no changes to the context and keep my edit as neutral as possible. [This is my suggested edit ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5230254):

[image]

It was approved, but I was uncertain why there are two votes for "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post."

Was my edit inaccurate? If I have replied or commented to a post, should I avoid editing it? And also, how could I learn and put better edits from this?

Comment: Tip for better editing: Remove noise such as "annoying problem" and "help me please". Clear concise posts are easier to understand. Such phrases have value only for OP, not for people who are trying to answer the question.

Comment: @Payeli Thanks for the advice. I believed it would modify the context, but apparently I should do it.

Comment: Please check my edit on the post. As for your original question, you had made a good edit, keep up the good work.

Comment: I don't really see a reason to reject this edit.

Comment: I bet some robo-reviewers thought it looked like those dodgy review audits and rejected your edit accordingly. BTW, the first sentence after your edit seems a bit off in my opinion.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy But it was ___my___ edit! And this is _meta_... >_>

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at here.

Comment: Oh, what are audits?

Comment: Audits are tests for reviewers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll explain this myself then!

The old reject reasons for reviewing suggested edits were based around "Edits are substantive improvements for the post", and hence a **"Too Minor"** reject reason was present, indicating the reviewers should approve approve-worthy edits.
My edit in question addressed superfluous improvements which did not *improve* the post, instead fixed problems which were not considered quality-blocking. Hence, reviewers raced to reject it, but headed for **"Invalid Edit"** instead, possibly due to the drastic changes based on the preview.

The suggested edits review queue has been revisited since then, and is now based upon "Edits are improvements or fixes for the post", such as code indentation to fit conventions, adding links to body, et cetera. The **"Invalid Edit"** reason has been changed to:

> #### clearly conflicts with author's intent
>
> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.
>
> #### attempt to reply
>
> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.