# 100 edits in one evening. Is it wrong?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

Yesterday I made over 100 edits. Why I did it?

1. To gain some badges and reputation points.
2. To make SO site a little better
3. Wanted to check if it is possible to gain 200 reputation points in one day this way.
4. I was curious how community will react for my unusual activity.

My edits were neither very valuable nor worthless.
For example:

1. When there was question about [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problem and it wasn't tagged [project-euler] and wasn't linked to this site, then I added tag and link.
2. Similarily with [4Clojure](https://www.4clojure.com) site
3. When question was about Fibonacci numbers and wasn't tagged [fibonacci] or about prime factorisation and wasn't tagged [prime-factoring] I added tag.
4. When I spotted spelling error or formatting code error in above questions I corrected them.

Result:

At the beginning my edit proposals were smoothly accepted. Then something started changing. Proposals waited longer for review. I spotted 'reject' votes. Proposals were accepted with score 3:1 or 3:2. Then several of my questions were rejected. I attracted several powerful users who voted against me.

Today I found following [discussion](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89/2014/11/8/3) on chat:

There are many hypotheses and opinions regarding me:

1. Is he trying to promote projecteuler.net?
2. So just rep farmer?
3. Perhaps users consider the tag useful.
4. The repeated behavior looks like spam to me.

Here are my answers:

1. I didn't do it to promote Project Euler site. Simply there were so many not tagged and linked Project Euler questions and only few not tagger 4Clojure question.
2. Few months ago I was solving problems from these two sites and found them interesting.
3. I think that my yesterday's edits were useful work. This work is not worth 200 rep points but doing edit there is no option 'I don't want rep points for this' (maybe it should be)
4. I don't plan another such experiment.
5. If there is [project-euler] tag (I didn't invented it) then questions regarding Euler problems should be tagged with this tag.
6. I think that even small edits are useful and are improving SO site.

What do you think about it? Was my activity wrong?

Comment: Looks you accused yourself for _'rep farming'_ :-P ...

Comment: Well, look at [your last edit for example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16251608/revisions). A link and a tag. The tag may be useful (though I don't really like the tag as such), but you didn't improve the question. We still have to visit an external site to see what it's about. How about making fewer edits and actually making good ones?

Comment: Generally if you're trying to figure out your 4th reason for doing this, you'd just ask how the community feels about it. There have been *many* discussions in the past about users mass retagging things (which is *mostly* what you say you were doing). It's not like there's a lack of information about it.

Comment: I should point out that [adding](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274528/289086) (or [removing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275935/289086)) project-euler is something that is the subject of debate.  You would probably be advised to not do it until this gets better settled.  The same could be said for *other* coding contest sites.  See also tangental discussion in [Burninate and blacklist the coursera tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274845/289086)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, the mass edits are considered abusive to the reviewers. Firstly, I would like to point to you that every reviewer only deals with at most 20 tasks every day (when the queue < 1k items, which it is), so when you put everyone through lots of your edits, the pool of robo-reviewers will be cleared, which is not good for massive retagging. Plus, you're doing it on weekends -> Even fewer robo reviewers -> robo reviewer pool drains up even more quickly. I learned this in the past where I also did massive edit batches.

*Ahem.*

In addition to the discussion you found, there's also [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19856252#19856252) in "the robo-reviewers' room":

> This user's edits *(links to your activity tab)* are vandalism, promoting project euler.

Which is a clear signal that you raised *someone*'s attention through what you've done and they decided to alert the reviewers through their robo-reviewers' room. Now, I would like to also share with you how your edits could be rejected:

### 1. Outstanding Potential Improvement

So I've went through and looked at your last four suggested edits as of yet. To comment (blue pen marks my comments):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

> I think that even small edits are useful and are improving SO site.

Having used up your pool of robo-reviewers by the first few dozens edits, the reviewers left are those who *actually rejects*. Having said that, your minor edits will of course fall short on luck and gets rejected.

### 2. Absolutely the worst edit comment

> added tag and link

is about as poor as:

> improved formatting

... Which most editors also use, however these should reflect your *intent* of editing and be *convincing* about getting it approved. When I was still suggesting edits, an edit comment of mine would look like this:

> Improved grammar, edited example layout to improve readability. Fixes title.

<lol

> Embed the pictures and improves grammar.

<lol

> Format numbered list for options.

<lol

> Formatted second code block with lang-none as it's not code. Indent code properly (another code formatting edit 1/5) and improved clarity and grammar.

These are all consecutive and arbitrarily-randomly chosen edits from [the currently 7th page of my Suggestions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622940/unihedron?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=7).

### 3. Digging through old posts

I'm short on time, so I'll make this short. Your editing spree covered old posts. There are no official guidelines on whether this is acceptable or preferred (as in editing old posts), however when you do the same repetitive edits on a lot of old posts *at least* it will ring a red alarm for the reviewers.

###Addressing your confusion:

> I didn't do it to promote Project Euler site. Simply there were so many not tagged and linked Project Euler questions and only few not tagger 4Clojure question.

[cleanup-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cleanup-request)

> Few months ago I was solving problems from these two sites and found them interesting.

That's... irrelevant, there's no questioning of whether the sites are good, just that *your edits* makes up for good rejecting targets.

> I think that my yesterday's edits were useful work. This work is not worth 200 rep points but doing edit there is no option 'I don't want rep points for this' (maybe it should be)

Users with [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) are supposed to do with the minor edits. If you're *suggesting edits*, you have to make it count. Read also: [Peer review edits use of "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." - accuracy?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262748/)

> I don't plan another such experiment.

Good.

> If there is [project-euler] tag (I didn't invented it) then questions regarding Euler problems should be tagged with this tag.

[retag-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request)

> > A lot of questions regarding [project-euler] has been mistagged, I would like to...

<lol

> I think that even small edits are useful and are improving SO site.

Yes, but you're not going to get your edits approved, simply because there's no pressing need to add 100 links to 100 posts (barely an improvement), which bumps those 100 questions **and** requires at least three reviewers' review for each of your edits. In conclusion, this turns out to be **a waste of everyone's time**. If you really want to help clean up bad questions, **post a meta thread first** (tagged appropriately of course), and **follow the editing guidelines**.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You mentioned digging old posts as not a good idea but there is a badge that encourages to editing old posts so I started from older posts.

Comment: @rtr Actually, I didn't imply whether editing old posts are a good idea- _"There are no official guidelines on whether this is acceptable or preferred"_. I've seen lots of Meta posts discussing this, the general consensus is that good edits should be approved regardless of post date and impact on bumping, and bad edits should get rejected regardless. What I was trying to convey was that editing in mass _followed by_ dealing with lots of old posts __will__ ring an alarm for most reviewers. It's not only fishy, but suspicious (and as you can see it already triggered someone else in "robo room").

Comment: (Sorry for the poor wording, my comment fell too long by five characters.)

Comment: Sadly, at least half of your markup would actually make the posts worse.  We don't "fix" style inside code blocks except when it's clear the poster has made no attempt to format at all (e.g. there is no indentation whatsoever).  And "maybe" would be grammatically incorrect there.  Just to analyze your first image.

Comment: Hey @BenVoigt, thanks for the reply. I too agree that some of the advices in my markup I've done should have been taken with a grain of salt, and "may be" should at most be "might be", but aside from that "code formatting edits" usually don't end well as a minor edit on itself. What I've noted as "fixing style" was really improving the readability where relevant, which is the essence of suggesting edits in the end.

Answer (score 10):

### My activity was wrong because:

1. I havn't done enough research before starting this mass edit
2. I wasted so much precious time of several super users.
3. My last edits were quick and uncautious. I corrected only tag and link. I haven't checked for other errors.
4. When I spotted first rejections I should stop editing. Instead I sped up.

### My activity was not wrong because:

1. In previous days I made several such edits and 100% of them were accepted. So there is a group of experienced users (with over 2k rep points) who confirmed that I've done something good. I havn't received any complaints.
2. One week earlier bjb568 asked this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler) propossing burnination of project-euler tag. Maybe he posted this question after he spotted my first pack of retag edits. So why wasn't I annonced about this post?
3. There is no limit of daily edits.
4. If existence of 'project-euler' tag is questioned then maybe automatic warning should be added if someone is trying to add this tag.
5. When I was doing my edits then some super users spotted this. They discussed my case on chat wondering who I am and what are my intentions. Why noone of them send me a message asking me to stop?
6. These super users rejected only 14 of my edits. But i still didn't received any message.
7. Next day I found this chat and wrote post explaining my behaviour.
8. In many of these edits I corrected spelling and code formatting. So retagging and linking wasn't my only activity.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276558/2982225

Comment: Only stack exchange employees (and maybe diamond moderators?) can directly contact a user.  The high rep users who assist in keeping the site healthy can leave a comment and hope you come back to that question... if you're touching over a hundred questions, how likely are you to see a comment added to one of them later?

Comment: @BenVoigt There is no way to contact someone directly but someone could send me a comment and I could spot the alert about it.

Answer (score 4):

They look suspiciously like spam, but even if they're not:

> This edit fails to make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Comment: It is a little easier to read question when you have direct link to Project Euler problem comparing to situation when you have only number of the problem and have to google it. In many of my edits I provided such direct link.

Comment: @rtruszk How does the specific question have to do at all with project euler? Assuming the question isn't a strait-up quote of project euler (as that wouldn't be on topic for SO and the focus would then be to close and delete rather that apply extremely minor edits), it will be a smaller subset of the problem likely (and if not, we don't especially care about it as it won't benefit the community) relating to many other similar (and not) problems in which case project euler is utterly irrelevant to the core of the question.