# Can one-letter edits be important?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, editing-help

An edit has to change at least 6 letters. So there is an assumption that an edit changing fewer number of letters cannot be important. But are there cases when changing (or adding, deleting) only one letter makes the edit important and worth accepting?

Correcting one character in a code example can make the code compile. But are there other examples?

Comment: _"So there is assumption that edit changing less number of letters cannon be important."_ It's more if you're under 2k rep, your edit is reviewed. If you're going to make a suggested edit, it should be worth the time of the reviewer and fix all problems with the post, make it easier to read, etc. Also note that editing "bumps" a question to the front of the "Active" tab in the question list, so if you make a lot of small edits that get approved, you will be noticed, and people won't be happy if it's a pointless edit that doesn't make the post even the slightest bit easier to read.

Comment: There are plenty of cases where the question is arguably well-written but an egregious misspelling sticks out like a sore thumb.  I agree with the OP that this should be able to be corrected without having to artificially find 6 characters of improvement.

Comment: Prior to getting editing privileges, I came across a post where a `<` was present where a `>` was clearly intended.  I suggested an edit and added text "(Please remove this line)" (http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/969417) which was rejected.  Probably looked like vandalism; e.g. if the reviewers didn't notice `<` changed to `>`.  So I added an explanation following the "Please remove" line (http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/969529).  That was accepted.  In retrospect, I could have backticked things in the post, but the intent of the edit was to fix the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, one letter edits can be important, but there is a very good reason for the 6-character limit. It prevents too many minor edits from new users who may not understand that every edit bumps the post back to the front page.

Users watch the front page looking for good questions to answer. A lot of questions get posted every minute, and finding a good question between all these posts is very difficult. On top of that, if many posts get old posts get bumped due to minor edits and flood the active tab, then the searching for questions to answer becomes even harder.

If you bump a post, make sure you fix all the issues. If it's a one character edit, you can consider leaving a comment under the post for the OP indicating that there is a typo.

On sites where I don't have full edit privileges, I generally follow the same. I leave a comment for the OP indicating the typo, so that when they edit the post, they can incorporate my suggestion and fix the one-character. Till now, I have always received positive response, as they generally fix it, and I remove my comment once it's fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It is about quality not quantity when it comes to edits. You can make as many changes as you want, but that doesn't mean the edit will substantially improve the post. However, you could make only one change, but it would have a far greater impact.

For example, I was trying to make a one letter edit on a question, in which case you would be able to understand the problem. The post involved Arrays, and they confused the indexing system from starting at 0 compared to starting at 1.

This is pretty significant as it changes the whole question.

I would say, don't focus on quantity but rather quality and yes, one letter edits can be valuable.