# How to deal with this 'series of Tag wiki edits'?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Noticed a certain user with a series of Tag-wiki edits ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7746948),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7746832),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7746888) to name a few) related to [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby),[mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)(current target). The edits mainly consisted of changing text from `See Also` to `Related Tags` which I rejected.

But *many* of them had a `Related tag : Ruby` section added. Is this allowed/relevant?

If these are not relevant edits, what is the process the flag this activity?

Comment: Good question. Looks like this guy is just after rep/badges. I would reject them too.

Comment: The sad thing is: At the end they will get to their goal even if you reject their edits! Because such people will make so many edits and if just enough goes through somehow, they will have the badge and they won't lose it even if you rollback the edits. (I also already saw a few people which just edits tag wiki with a wikipedia copy&paste OR just do an edit where they change `i` -> `I` OR they create a new tag retag 50 questions to their tag and then leave it)

Comment: Till now I have skipped 30+ edits and still getting one of those. Just doesn't seem to stop.!

Comment: I wrote a MSO answer for a similar occasion in the past: [100 edits in one evening. Is it wrong?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276402/100-edits-in-one-evening-is-it-wrong/276435#276435)

Comment: @ShaunakD That's what I mean ^ they will only stop if they get to their goal and they will do so many edits until enough goes through and they reached their goal

Comment: @Rizier123, exactly. I don't think we can control/prevent this.

Comment: I used all my 20 review votes to reject the edits.

Comment: Just open [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3563993/shilovk?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and visit all pending edits. Reject if needed.

Comment: This says it all [User has received the badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1656/research-assistant?userid=3563993)

Comment: @rene I slowly hating the argument: `Every "little" edit improves SO posts`. Because the reality is that it's just wasting time of reviewers (Like you)! And also why only change like 1x `i` -> `I` when you could also improve other things like:  formatting, title and tags?! (So for myself when I do and edit then I improve as much as I can, not only one thing!) So their should maybe a reject reason for such edits from such users

Comment: I raised an Other flag on one of the posts of that editor and asked for a moderator to step in.

Comment: @rene I wonder if your flag will be helpful and the mods will reverse the edits, if they also take the badge away or if he will keep it. (I think sadly he will keep the badge so the users won't bother if the edits gets reversed)

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't mind about the badges, first prio is to get this stopped and then we'll see how we can clean up. We have the history of what is touched

Comment: @rene Well then I think actually the fasted way with such users which do such edits would be just to leave them until they get their badge/goal. And then just flag it for a mod. So that the work for all people/reviewers/mods will be as low as possible. (But then I wouldn't like that we wouldn't do anything against this behavior from users)

Comment: @shilovk editing every tag wiki to link to every other semi-related tag in some giant circle is completely useless.  That's not actually improving any of the wikis.

Comment: @shilovk Some of your edits make things worse: how is mysqli (PHP) related to mysql2 (Ruby)? Why did you remove the info to use [ruby] in addition to the version-specific tags?

Comment: @shilovk those edits are no improvement and waste the time of reviewers (and reviews)

Comment: @shilovk, I myself am a small user compared to others here. It doesn't have anything to with your reputation/rank on the site. Your edits could be misleading to new users and adding related tag as `ruby` to `rubyonrails-3..` is just of no improvement. Even a guy who does not understand programming would know that these are related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Evaluate them by their specific intrinsic value.

> But many of them had a Related tag : Ruby section added. Is this allowed/relevant?

They are trying to consistently relate a type of post about a topic which **relevance is crucial** for them: approve them.

> If these are not relevant edits, what is the process the flag this activity?

They are just plain wrong, or irrelevant changes: **reject them.**

That it's done by a single users or several is not a element to take into account, but that each specific edit improves the quality of the post.

Comment: So you say in the end it is not an issue that 100 suggested edits by a single user are all rejected? Nothing else needs to be done?

Comment: @rene obviously if all of them are/should be rejected, there would be a problem and the system should kick in to slowdown/prevent further damage. When I say "system" I refer to any: moderators, users, flags, Community.

Comment: Okay, that is were this question is about. I don't see that aspect very much addressed in your answer. Can you elaborate if the actions taken so far (meta-post, comment left for the OP, flagged for a moderator, organizing an reject squad) are things we as a community should do?

Comment: @rene I said what the community should do, so I'm just reiterating: they are good, approve, they are bad, reject.

Comment: @shilovk I actually rejected some of them for being non-sensical. I suggest that you slow down and actually read the question. Remember, tags are not applied just because a keywords is mentioned, they have to be relevant to the problem presented.

Comment: @shilovk Yes and the reviewers make their own decisions. You're free to open a meta-post to argue that some of your edits were rejected due to this post but the outcome might be different then what you expect. The 20 that I rejected didn't qualify for making the post better.

Comment: @shilovk, IMO rene's intention was just to tell you that you were going wrong and he was the one to make you aware of this post so that you could clarify your reason behind these edits. I posted this question just to know whether what you did was right or wrong. Nobody would/should downvote you for this.