# Tag Wiki bulk editing

Tags: discussion, edits

There's a user that in 3 hours has racked up 5 pages of activity for tag wiki edits, they seem to be flooding the review queue and from what I can see they are nearly all just changing the word "Documentation" to "Resources"

Really??

I'm not naming them publicly (although anyone in the review queue will probably realise who they are) but is there anything to discourage this kind of thing? or a script to pick this kind of behaviour up? I assume it's just for getting a silver badge *woohoo*...

It's just generating lots of needless work for us.

Comment: Uh... That's weird. Is there any other changes or hidden gems in the edits? It's also probably grounds for a moderator flag - just link to the user and describe the situation, ideally with an example.

Comment: The real issue is that people are *approving* these edits. If they weren't, he'd have been blocked from submitting them a long time ago. Time for a moderator to hand out some review bans...

Comment: @CodyGray here, here! After rejecting a couple for no improvement I thought I was going mad and just seeing the same edit over and over! I see the researcher badge has already been awarded to the individual, doesn't seem to slow them down though....

Comment: Hmm... when the real Documentation feature rolls out, we might want to rename headers in this fashion. This user is ahead of the times! ;)

Comment: I've done some rejects as well as one other member from the SOCVR. It is not a clear-cut case though.

Comment: I've rejected a lot of edits made to the excerpts with @rene but the case of the wiki themselves is debatable. Adding a "Relevant tags" section, as was done on most of the edits, is not discouraged: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290752/1743880

Comment: @rene I agree in the sense that there's not techincally anything _wrong_ with the edits per-se. But at some point we need a common sense check on excessive minor edits like this that don't appear to serve any real benefit to the community.

Comment: I'd impose a temporary edit ban here, but unfortunately since this is a 4k user, they aren't subject to the normal suggested edit process. Only their tag wiki edits are reviewed, so it appears the normal suggested edit ban process doesn't function for them.

Comment: @BradLarson : I guess this is a reference to the edits I've been doing the last couple of days, in an attempt to improve a pretty messy & inconsistent Wiki tag database. Most of the edits involve either (1) adding, improving ör normalizing references to related tags, (2) adding, improving ör normalizing references to useful links and (3) normalizing / improving various other (usually minor) elements of the tag wikis. While some of these - I guess - may be too minor changes for your taste, I do believe that each of these individual edits is an improvement with respect to the situation before.

Comment: Anyway, I will refrain from making any further edits until I'm notified on (1) whether or not I'm allowed to make minor improvements like the ones I've been making and (2) which kind of edits ARE considered constructive... because (at least in my opinion) I have not made a single edit that doesn't improve the overall quality of the Tag Wiki...

Comment: @JohnSlegers but to be fair, there are [some edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11350173) that I would reject any day of the week because they are superfluous. If it's adding value, I'm all for it - and perhaps for 'bulk' edits there should be a better system than having to go through the review queue. But for things like changing the word "visit" to "go" it's just a waste of time.

Comment: @MacroMan : Are there some kind of guidelines for which terms to use for various sections of a Wiki, which text formatting to use for titles, whether or not to use horizontal rules between sections, etc?! This would make things a lot easier for both people editing Wiki's and people (dis)approving them. If not, it seems to me the rules as they are today are way, way too ambiguous and incomplete, resulting in (1) many people just following their gut feeling or the most subjective, arbitrary rules and (2) there being a Kafkaesque lack of consistency in both content and layout of Wikis.

Comment: @JohnSlegers It certainly would make it a lot easier for people editing and unfortunately this is the 'danger zone' that can lead into endless debate - In my personal opinion, if it ain't broke - don't fix it. But the issue with community moderation is that _it's just my opinion_ - if you want to change something there's nothing stopping you. My issues isn't neccessarily with the _content_ of the edits, just that I feel a wiki was fine the way it was, so reviewing it is unneccesary work for the community. You can stop editing, I can stop reviewing - it's swings and roundabouts.

Comment: OK, let me chime in here as one of the rejectors. There are a couple of things that stood out in your edits @JohnSlegers. In the excerpt just replacing the first word or remove a . is just not the kind of improvement that makes the three 5K-rep users that need to approve your edit very happy. Specially not if the comment only says *deleted 1 character in body* . Now it looks like you've taken on something. That is great but if it impacts then you better create a meta post first so you can link to that from your edit comment.

Comment: Additionally you might get extra tips and guidance on how to approach that, what to edit and what not. Maybe you get some help from user who do have direct edit privilege for wiki's.

Comment: To (hopefully) round this off - I think these kind of issues are always going to arise because we have to justify our rejections with a reason, but we don't have to justify approvals. So intrinsically, we _actively look_ for reasons to reject an edit but we don't specifically look for reasons to accept it. Perhaps another question for another time...

Comment: @MacroMan :  **if you want to change something there's nothing stopping you** - Well, I guess there is. If a moderator like Brad Larson believes too many minor edits are a sufficient reason for a temporary edit ban, that does warrant some caution.

Comment: @MacroMan : **I feel a wiki was fine the way it was, so reviewing it is unneccesary work for the community.** - I guess I'm too much of a sucker for consistency and readability. To quote AwolNation : "Blame it on my ADD, baby!" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgIqecROs5M)

Comment: I've re-opened this so we can maybe put all these useful comments in a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Evaluate each edit in isolation.** Approve if the edit is good, improve if it can be improved, reject if it's detrimental to the post and reject and edit if you feel that the tag wiki needs another kind of work.

Remember, no matter what, the review queue has never gotten "flooded" or "clogged", I would expect a meta post of users asking why they can't suggest edits by now if this was a problem.

Recommended read [How to deal with serial tag-only edits from Sub 2k users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314488/)